# How to check whether the key is present inside the array of stdclass objects in php?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

i have two arrays one is the type of stdclass object and another one is normal array like this

```
$array1 = ['name'=>'laravel','duration'=>'40']; // noraml-array
//array2 is a stdobject array
$array2 = [
  0 => {#3954
    +"name": "php"
    +"duration": "30"
  }
  1 => {#3900
    +"author": "apiato"
    +"duration": "15"
  }
]
```

i am writing one function in a generic way inside that i want to add one check weather name key exists or not for that i am using **array_key_exists** function it works fine for normal array,but it's not working for **$array2** ,can you please help me how to differentiate both arrays or how to check with **array_key_exists()** only...?

Comment: well, array_key_exists() doesn't work on objects, only on arrays... You'd have to use another method (like isset(), or property_exists() )

Comment: Is it not a possibility to convert your stdClass to an array? You could do something like: `$array2 = json_decode(json_encode($array2), true)`